# web3.js - how to check if a Token Contract implements ERC223 standard?

Tags: solidity, web3js, erc20

I would like to receive payments in any given ERC20 Token.

For that, the user must fisrt approve the transaction calling...

```
function approve(address, uint)
```

... on the Token's contract and then call to a specific function on MyContract that will triggers the actual transfer, calling...

```
function transferFrom(address from, address to, uint tokens)
```

... again on the Tokens's contract

That works fine but is very tedius and has double gas spending.

---

Now I found out the ERC223 standard that solves this (and other issues) but is not implemented by the mayority of the current popular tokens. It would be great to give the user the opportunity to pay just making a single transaccion when posible.

So, how can I dynamicaly check if a given token address implements ERC223 standar using web3 v0.x (im using v0.20.4) ?